# Flask objects on multiple sessions when they not should be

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a similar problem to the user here: [SQLAlchemy Object already attached to session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291933/sqlalchemy-object-already-attached-to-session)

And I'm getting basically the same error:

```
'<Link at 0x7f31a785f630>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '15')
```

I'm really trying to figure out why multiple sessions are being created, when I only want one. I have two files `__init__.py` and `models.py`:

Lines of interest from `__init__.py`:

```
from .models import User, draft_new_link_message, load_history, load_messages, db
# Initialize app and such
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.secret_key = 'super secret keyssss'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
db.init_app(app)
app.app_context().push()

...

db.create_all()
```

From `models.py`:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Link(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'link'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    originator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    originator = db.relationship("User", back_populates='history')
```

From these lines alone, it seems that I should be on one session. If I'm not, how do I format my code correctly to reduce headaches and make sure I don't have to transfer objects between sessions? Thanks!

**Edit: Solution**

The reason I structured my project this way was because a few pieces of documentation said this was the correct pattern (creating the db inside your models file and then callng db.init_app() to get it into the main file). But I guess this was a bad idea. I thought maybe I had to because I can't have both the files reference each other. But to get around this  I wrote a method in the main file to get the db and called the import on the models function

My new `__init__.py`:
    # Initialize app and such
    app = Flask(**name**)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///browse_together.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
    app.secret_key = 'super secret keysssss'
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

```
# Provide a way for models.py (and any other files that needs it) to get access to the database
def get_db():
    return db


# Now you can import models.py because it can use this database
from . import urltils, models
from .models import User, Group, get_groups, create_group, \
    draft_new_link_message, load_history, load_messages, toggle_send
```

The new first few lines from `models.py`:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import urltils
from . import get_db

# Get an instance of the db from __init__
db = get_db()
```

I think this is more correct.

Comment: Where did you create a Session?

Comment: I never explicity created a session... Should I have?? Whenever I want to use the session I call db.session. What did I do wrong? Updated the post with a bit more code that may or may not be helpful.

Comment: You should define db when bootstrap app not in models,see http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/

Comment: @mirhossein then how do I reference db from inside models?

Comment: just import it from where you defined db session

Comment: Thanks @mirhossein I think this is good advice, better practice than what I was doing. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I structured my project this way was because a few pieces of documentation said this was the correct pattern (creating the db inside your models file and then callng db.init_app() to get it into the main file). But I guess this was a bad idea. I thought maybe I had to because I can't have both the files reference each other. But to get around this I wrote a method in the main file to get the db and called the import on the models function

My new `__init__.py`:

```
# Other imports...

# Initialize app and such 
app = Flask(name)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my.db' 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True 
app.secret_key = 'super secret keysssss' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Provide a way for models.py (and any other files that needs it) to get access to the database
def get_db():
    return db


# Now you can import models.py because it can use this database
from . import urltils, models
from .models import User, Group, get_groups, create_group, \
    draft_new_link_message, load_history, load_messages, toggle_send
```

The new first few lines from `models.py`:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import urltils
from . import get_db

# Get an instance of the db from __init__
db = get_db()
```

I think this is more correct.